# Why a static field of a class, which is not serializable, will throw NotSerializableException when an instance being serialized?

Tags: java, scala, serializable

In scala, I think a  field of a object will be static and not be serialized when serializing, 
but if the field is non serializable, a NotSerializableException got.
Why ? Similar java code is OK.

Below is a simple example.

Thanks

Scala code:

```
package test

import java.io._
import java.util

object AStudent extends Serializable {
  var name="Jack"
  val map=new util.WeakHashMap

}

object SerializationDemo extends App {

  val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./tmp/stu"))
  println(AStudent.name)
  AStudent.name=null
  println(AStudent.name)
  oos.writeObject(AStudent)
  oos.close

}
```

Java code:

```
package test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

public class Stu implements Serializable {
    public static String name="Jack";
    public static WeakHashMap map=new WeakHashMap();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./tmp/stu"));
        oos.writeObject(new Stu());
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: In general when asking about exceptions you might want to add the stacktrace. Besides that note that the Scala code and the Java code should not be equivalent (although I don't know Scala very much) as one has instance fields while the other has class fields (aka static).

Comment: Scala has no concept of `static` fields. You can "think" of members of an object `A` as being similar to `static` in Java. Keywords being "think similar" and not actually being static. The object `AStudent` will be an instance of an anonymous class `AStudent.type` and all the members of object `AStudent` are actually members of class `AStudent.type`.

Answer (score 0):

The examples are not equivalent. In Java example you are serializing a `Stu` instance, the serialization will skip `static` fields as they are not part of the instance state. In Scala example you are serializing a `AStudent` object instance which has a `map` field. Since Scala don't have `static` concept, the Java equivalent would be:

```
public class AStudent implements Serializable {
  public Map map = new WeakHashMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala has no concept of `static` fields. You can "think" of members of an object A as being similar to `static` in Java.

Keywords being "think similar to static" and not actually being `static`.

The object `AStudent` will be an instance of an anonymous class `AStudent.type` and all the members of object `AStudent` are actually members of class `AStudent.type`

It is similar to,

```
class AStudentType[K, V](
    var name: String ="Jack",
    val map: WeakHashMap[K, V] = new WeakHashMap()
)

val AStudent = new AStudentType[String, String]()
```